# When should scope annotation be used

Tags: java, scope, guice

What does the scope annotation in Java guice mean?

Could someone give an example to explain how it works?
I see examples like this:

```
@Singleton
class Log {
  void log(String message) { ... }
}
```

But singleton has nothing to do with scope, right?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Scopes allow you to reuse instances: for the lifetime of an application (@Singleton), a session (@SessionScoped), or a request (@RequestScoped).

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes

It means that if your class is annotated with Singleton there will be only one object instantiated from this class which will be injected every time you will use this kind of bind.

When you use @RequestScoped you get every time new object per request